# how to keep track of time (to have player ignore damage for 3 seconds)?

Tags: java

I have some code that looks like this:

```
if there is a collision between player and enemy
    player.health--
```

I want to do this:

```
if there is a collision between player and enemy
    player.health--
    wait for 3 seconds
```

This is to ignore collision for a bit so player's health doesn't instantly drop to 0.

How would I implement some sort of timer for this?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(3000)` is one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to not freeze the movement you would have to either start a new Thread like this

```
private Thread invul;

if(collision && (invul==null || !invul.isAlive())){
    player.health--;
    invul=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    };
    invul.start();
}
```

---

or maybe simpler save the time the player was hit.

```
private long lastTimeHit= 0;

if(collision && System.currentTimeMillis() > lastTimeHit+3000){
    lastTimeHit= System.currentTimeMillis();
    player.health--;
}
```

Comment: The first solution also leaves the possibility to add some animation: `public void run() { player.blinking = true; Thread.sleep(3000); pla<yer.blinking = false; }`. The blinking member can then be interpreted by the graphics engine.

Comment: I don't think spinning up a thread to do this would be the optimal solution. I'd personally do something like `player.invulnerableUntil` to store a time. That can be also interpreted as a visual cue.